# how to get the string after specific substring jquery

Tags: javascript, string

i have a string like this

```
var url="http://localhost/elephanti2/chaink/stores/stores_ajax_page/5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11"
```

i want to get the string after the `7 th slash(/)`

here it would be `5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jquery for this, just pure JS.

```
var url= "http://localhost/elephanti2/chaink/stores/stores_ajax_page/5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11"
re = /^([^\/]*\/){7}(.+)/
result = url.match(re)[2]
```

Regular expressions in javascript: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Rather than counting slashes, you should probably look for the part of the path right after a marker such as this:

```
var url="http://localhost/elephanti2/chaink/stores/stores_ajax_page/5/b.BusinessName/asc/1/11";
var endPath = url.replace(/^.*\/stores_ajax_page\//, "");
```

This is a little less brittle if the front part of the path ever gets changed.

Comment: hmm in this case the name stores_ajax_page changes , so i can not use , this , anyway thankyou very much ........... :)

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya - Wouldn't you still be better off anchoring to some part of the path rather than counting slashes?

Comment: mmm your script is not working --->>> unterminated regular expression  
var endPath = url.replace(/^.*\/stores_ajax_page\/, "");

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya - I fixed a typo in the regular expression.